# Call Page_Load from a Protected Sub VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I've got a front facing ASPX page that displays several buttons and preforms the code requested. The issue is that I'm reading a relay and so my current state of the web relay is always behind due to my page refresh so I'm thinking I just need to start at the Page_Load event to make this happen correctly and regenerate the status of the relay.

My question is, how do I call the Page_Load() from within the button Click sub?

```
'Global Gate Interface
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim tcpClient As New TcpClient()

    'Connect to webrelay
    tcpClient.Connect("xx.xx.xx.xx", 80)

    'Create a network stream object
    Dim netStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()

    'Create the XML command to send to Webrelay
    Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET /state.xml HTTP/1.1" & vbCrLf & "Authorization: Basic bm9uZTp3ZWJyZWxheQ==" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

    'Send the command to webrelay
    netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

    'Get the response from webrelay
    Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    netStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))

    'Convert the bytes received from Webrelay into a string
    Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)

    'Convert the string into and array
    Dim array1 As Char() = returndata.ToCharArray()

    'Relay State found at index 66 of array
    If array1(66) = "1" Then
        relayState.Text = "ON"
    Else
        relayState.Text = "OFF"
    End If

    'Input State found at index 94 of array
    If array1(94) = "1" Then
        inputState.Text = "ON"
    Else
        inputState.Text = "OFF"
    End If

    'Close the connection
    tcpClient.Close()


End Sub

'Turn East relay On
Protected Sub relayOnEast_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles eastOpen.Click

    Dim tcpClient As New TcpClient()

    'Connect to webrelay
    tcpClient.Connect("xx.xx.xx.xx", 80)

    'Create a network stream object
    Dim netStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()

    'Create the XML command to send to Webrelay
    Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET /state.xml?relayState=1 HTTP/1.1<CR><LF>" & vbCrLf & "Authorization: Basic bm9uZTp3ZWJyZWxheQ==<CR><LF><CR><LF>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

    'Send the command to webrelay
    netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

    'Close the connection
    tcpClient.Close()

'RERUN PAGE LOAD HERE?



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code that is inside the protected sub into a separate sub maybe like this
and then call the new sub from the form load event. And then you can call the same code from your other sub.

```
Protected sub PageReload
    Dim tcpClient As New TcpClient()

    'Connect to webrelay
    tcpClient.Connect("xx.xx.xx.xx", 80)

    'Create a network stream object
    Dim netStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()

    'Create the XML command to send to Webrelay
    Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET /state.xml HTTP/1.1" & vbCrLf & "Authorization: Basic bm9uZTp3ZWJyZWxheQ==" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

    'Send the command to webrelay
    netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

    'Get the response from webrelay
    Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    netStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))

    'Convert the bytes received from Webrelay into a string
    Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)

    'Convert the string into and array
    Dim array1 As Char() = returndata.ToCharArray()

    'Relay State found at index 66 of array
    If array1(66) = "1" Then
        relayState.Text = "ON"
    Else
        relayState.Text = "OFF"
    End If

    'Input State found at index 94 of array
    If array1(94) = "1" Then
        inputState.Text = "ON"
    Else
        inputState.Text = "OFF"
    End If

    'Close the connection
    tcpClient.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move the code from `Page_Load()` to a separate private method and call that method in `Page_Load()` and `relayOnEast_Click()`.

Side note: this might not work as you have to pay attention to the life cycle of a ASPX page.